# How to ensure Netgear GS724TP is not blocking Dropbox Lan Sync - port 17500

Tags: port, local-area-network, synchronization, netgear, dropbox

We're a small company using Drop Box for business but have noticed that Lan Sync refuses to work on our network (it works fine at home).

After [trouble shooting the issues on the Dropbox forums](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=118245&replies=10), it's been suggested that something on our network is blocking Lan Sync on port 17500.

We have:

- Netgear GS724TP managed switched
- Netcomm consumer ADSL modem

I've been through the control panels of both devices and while the firewall is off on the ADSL modem, I can't figure out what I should be looking for on the Netgear managed switch.

Does anyone know how to configure the Netgear switch so Dropbox Lan Sync works?

Cheers

Ben

Comment: Managed switches don't block things unless you configure them to - so if you DIDN'T setup any sort of filtering on the switch, then that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the advice you were given, it's quite unlikely to be the switch.  Most managed switches do have some filtering and routing capabilities, but they all default to being off.  Unless you've explicitly enabled them, the switch shouldn't be filtering anything.

There are a few things I can think of to check (and I know from your thread that you checked many of these, but it never hurts to start from the beginning):

- Make sure all the clients are on the same broadcast domain.  In your case, that means all connected to the switch, and all on the same VLAN (if you are using VLANs).  Particularly if you are using wireless, this might be the issue.  Some router/modem combination devices do not pass broadcast traffic between the wired and wireless ports.  Test with the computers all connected to the same switch by ethernet.

  - Make sure LAN sync isn't disabled in the dropbox options on each computer.  It can disable itself under some circumstances.
  - Make sure no firewalls are blocking dropbox traffic.  This may also include some antivirus programs that interfere with broadcast traffic
  - If all that checks out, breakout [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) on two machines that should be syncing with each other and make sure they see each other's broadcast traffic.  Wireshark has decoders for dropbox traffic, so it will show up as "Dropbox LAN Sync Discovery Protocol".  If you don't see any such traffic, or you do see the packets from computer A on computer B and vis versa, then it's not a network issue.  If you see them being sent, but not received on the other PCs, something is blocking it.

Comment: Thanks heaps - I'll double check the settings and look at Wireshark. Cheers Ben